# Create and import pgsql database after pg_dump

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to postgres.  I have exported a large, complex database with the following command in the terminal

```
pg_dump -U USERNAME DBNAME > dbexport.pgsql
```

Now that I have transferred this .pgsql file to a different computer, what is the right command to automatically create and restore the exact same database as was exported?  Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: `psql -f dbexport.pgsql` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you dumped the database, the information about the database itself is not included in the dump (which is a plain SQL file).

You can either use the `-C` option to include `CREATE DATABASE` in the dump (the dump has to be restored with `psql`), or you use the custom format:

```
pg_dump -F c -U postgres DBNAME -f dbexport.pgsql
```

That can be restored with `pg_restore` like this:

```
pg_restore -C -d postgres -U postgres dbexport.pgsql
```

Comment: why does `pg_dump -U USERNAME DBNAME > dbexport.pgsql` produce a 400 MB file whereas `pg_dump -F c -U postgres DBNAME -f dbexport.pgsql` produces a 70 MB file?

Comment: Because the custom format is compressed. One of its advantages.